# How to rebase branch in IBM Clear Case

Tags: branch, clearcase, rebase

My colleague created a feature branch about a year ago and checked in some modification on it. Now I need to continue with it but During the time files was changed on the main branch too.
Now I need to rebase feature branch to main latest and merge changes from main to my feature branch.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`cleartool rebase`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rebase.htm) is a term from UCM ClearCase, and applies to a baseline (a label on all elements of an UCM component -- or set of files).

If you are not using UCM, the equivalent would be to put a label on the LATEST of the elements in your branch.

In both cases (UCM or non-UCM), the end-result of that rebase would be to merge the main branch into the feature branch.

In non-UCM, this is a simple [`cleartool merge`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_merge.htm) (you don't need the initial LABEL: it is just to memorize the state of the feature branch *before* the merge)

Warning: that "rebase" is not like a rebase in a distributed VCS like Git, where commits (versioned set of files) are replayed. Here, ClearCase is file-centric, which means it will only do merges.